# how to open external links in to there relevant app in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I converted my website into android app via webview. The website has some external links. All those links have there android app example facebook, twitter, amazon, ebay etc.

What I want is when someone use my app and click on those external links then the link should open in there relevant app if that install. If app is not install then it should open in browser.

Right now, When I click on links my app gives options whether to open link in chrome or firefox.
Is it possible to add option of relevant app with browsers? I have been searching solution for last 2 days. Tried multiple codes but none worked.

UPDATE:
For better understanding. I am from India and here Amazon, Flipkart(ecommerce site) are popular. So I make website and put two links out there.

```
<a href="https://amazon.com">Amazon</a>
and <a href="https://flipkart.com">Flipkart</a>
```

Now, On your android phone. Install Amazon and Flipkart application. Convert your website into android app. Call that page which has above two links.

You will notice that when you click on Amazon link it ask to open in chrome and other browsers. But when you click on flipkart it gives it's app option along with other browsers.

Comment: Please give examples of links that do not give the actions you want. This is all too vague now. Come to the point. Put them in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: What links bro. We all know Amazon, Ebay, Facebook etc. Do i need to put links as well?

Comment: Yes. Didnt i ask for that?

Comment: Every time the user clicks a link the webview produces an event. I forgot the name but it is something like onBeforeLoad or onNewUrl or whatever it is called. You can inspect the url there and start the application you want. Personaly i hate it when i click a link in a browser and an app is opened instead of the normal website. Like google does with google maps. So you better give the user a choice instead of blindly opening an app.

Comment: `Convert your website into android app.`? What should that be?

Comment: I dont want to open app directly but when people click on link then they should get option where they want to open the link like in browser or in relevant app.

Comment: @greenapps Convert you website into android app means to call your website with in an app via web view. :-(

Comment: Ok. But with using a webview to display a site one is not converting a website to an app. Strange way of talking. One would merely use a webview instead of a browser app. When people click on a link you get an event. Use it! I already told you how.

Answer (score 0):

```
Context contex=this;
try {
//just use package name of your app which you want to open
Intent i = contex.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.twidroid.SendTweet");
contex.startActivity(i);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: but how to connect "com.twidroid.senttweet" with specific URL?

Comment: This is package name of you apps which you want to open.
Like 
Facebook = "com.facebook.katana"